# angularjs ng-option in nested ng-repeat binding to model issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this issue where my select model is binding to two or more select depending on the length of the parent array.
for you to understand this is my jsonArray

```
[
    {
        "id": 19,
        "subSpecialtyId": 1,
        "institutionAccreditationApplicationId": 13,
        "subSpecialtyName": "Chromatography",
        "exams": [
            {
                "id": 1001,
                "name": "Part 1",
                "departmentId": 0,
                "designation": null,
                "index": 4,
                "statuses": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Full",
                        "departmentId": 0,
                        "designation": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Partial",
                        "departmentId": 0,
                        "designation": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "Denied",
                        "departmentId": 0,
                        "designation": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 1002,
                        "name": "Full for Part 1",
                        "departmentId": 0,
                        "designation": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 1002,
                "name": "Part II",
                "departmentId": 0,
                "designation": null,
                "index": 5,
                "statuses": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Full",
                        "departmentId": 0,
                        "designation": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Partial",
                        "departmentId": 0,
                        "designation": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "Denied",
                        "departmentId": 0,
                        "designation": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 1002,
                        "name": "Full for Part 1",
                        "departmentId": 0,
                        "designation": null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "subSpecialtyId": 4,
        "institutionAccreditationApplicationId": 13,
        "subSpecialtyName": "Sub Specialty F",
        "exams": [
            {
                "id": 1001,
                "name": "Part 1",
                "departmentId": 0,
                "designation": null,
                "index": 4,
                "statuses": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Full",
                        "departmentId": 0,
                        "designation": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Partial",
                        "departmentId": 0,
                        "designation": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "Denied",
                        "departmentId": 0,
                        "designation": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 1002,
                        "name": "Full for Part 1",
                        "departmentId": 0,
                        "designation": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 1002,
                "name": "Part II",
                "departmentId": 0,
                "designation": null,
                "index": 5,
                "statuses": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Full",
                        "departmentId": 0,
                        "designation": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Partial",
                        "departmentId": 0,
                        "designation": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "Denied",
                        "departmentId": 0,
                        "designation": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 1002,
                        "name": "Full for Part 1",
                        "departmentId": 0,
                        "designation": null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and this is my snippet for html which am using to try and bind the json to

```
<table ng-if="item.subSpecialties.length>0" class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="100" class="text-center">{{item.facultyName}}</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    {{item.subSpecialties.length>1?'Sub Specialties':'Sub Specialty'}}
                                </th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>{{item.subSpecialties|json}}</tr>
                            <tr ng-repeat="x in item.subSpecialties track by x.subSpecialtyId">
                                <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                                <td>{{x.subSpecialtyName}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <table class="table">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Exam</th>
                                            <th>Status</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        <tr ng-repeat="exam in x.exams">
                                            <td>{{exam.name}}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <select class="form-control" dynamic-validation="{required:true}"  ng-model="exam.accreditationStatusId" ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in exam.statuses">
                                                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>{{$parent.$index}} - {{$index}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

the issue i have is available in this picture below
[image: Issue picture]
On selection of the First option for Exam 1 in subspecialty 1 the option of Exam 1 option 2 is also selected i use the indexs on the right of the select to keep track of the selection array but the model is binding to the last index only and not considering the parent index

I have also tried to set the model based on the parent Index like this

```
 <select class="form-control" dynamic-validation="{required:true}"  ng-model="item.subSpecialties[$parent.$index].selection[exam.id].accreditationStatusId" ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in statuses">
```

--Select--
  
But the object the model form cannot be easily parsed.
Thanks in anticipation of your response

**UPDATE**
After i did the plunker and i discovered it was working then i took time to inspect the element of my browser i discovered the following difference 
[image: Project rendering of the select option]

and for the plunker rendering
[image]

Mind that i am using thesame version of angular in project and in plunker.....
What i want to know is how do i convert the index in project.. Though i am using Typescript...

Comment: can you create plunker?

Comment: This is the plunker  https://plnkr.co/edit/Vwsilm1611KfVZyXEpUX?p=preview

Comment: Discovered it working in the plunker but not working stil in my project